# Get Frequency using a loop in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am triying to get individual frequency table for each variable using a loop and dplyr package, example of my code is below using mtcars data:

```
library(dplyr)

var= c("vs", "am", "gear")

for (i in var){
mtcars %>%
group_by(carb) %>%
count(i)
}
```

Lamentably only i get:

```
Error: Column `i` is unknown
```

I also tried with

```
for (i in var){
mtcars %>%
group_by(carb) %>%
summarise_each(funs(n()), i)
}
```

But not succces, 
Please any advice I will gratefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `!!sym()` for the variable names. I would also recommend to save the results to a list as follows.

```
var <- c("vs", "am", "gear")

library(dplyr)

count_tables <- list()

for (i in var){
  temp <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(carb) %>%
    count(!!sym(i))

  count_tables[[i]] <- temp       
}

count_tables
# $vs
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# # Groups:   carb [6]
#    carb    vs     n
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     1     7
# 2     2     0     5
# 3     2     1     5
# 4     3     0     3
# 5     4     0     8
# 6     4     1     2
# 7     6     0     1
# 8     8     0     1
# 
# $am
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
# # Groups:   carb [6]
#   carb    am     n
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     0     3
# 2     1     1     4
# 3     2     0     6
# 4     2     1     4
# 5     3     0     3
# 6     4     0     7
# 7     4     1     3
# 8     6     1     1
# 9     8     1     1
# 
# $gear
# # A tibble: 11 x 3
# # Groups:   carb [6]
#     carb  gear     n
#    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#  1     1     3     3
#  2     1     4     4
#  3     2     3     4
#  4     2     4     4
#  5     2     5     2
#  6     3     3     3
#  7     4     3     5
#  8     4     4     4
#  9     4     5     1
# 10     6     5     1
# 11     8     5     1
```

It is also common to use `lapply` to loop through a vector or a list to apply a function and return the objects as a list. The following generates the same output as the for-loop.

```
count_tables <- lapply(var, function(x) {
  mtcars %>%
    group_by(carb) %>%
    count(!!sym(i))
})
names(count_tables) <- var
```

Answer (score 0):

For programmatically passing the variable as a string, you can use the version of those functions with and underscore at the end, such as `count_`, `group_by_`, etc.

In this case it would be:

```
for (i in var){
  mtcars %>%
    group_by(carb) %>%
    count_(i) %>% 
    print()
}
```

You specifically asked for a `for` loop, but for your consideration, here goes a `lapply` alternative, which makes it easier to store the different results in one place for later access:

```
lapply(var, FUN = function(i) mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% count_(i))
```

Comment: `count_()` is deprecated. Please use `count` with `tidyeval` (https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/).